# Issue with update operation in the database table

Tags: mysql, arduino, esp32

I am facing an issue with update operation in the database table. Sometimes update query is not getting success and the MySql library (MySQL_MariaDB_Generic) on the gateway side is showing the error “MySQL_Packet::read_packet:  ERROR: Timeout waiting for client".

I am using the AWS RDS server for the MYSQL database. MYSQL version is 8.0.20. And the query is executed from the ESP32 Wi-Fi module.

From my gateway application, I am inserting the data in 3 steps for 3 data fields as data size is large (around 10k). First I am inserting a record and then adding more data through the update query. The Insert query is successful every time but the update query fails sometimes even though  I retry 10 times continuously.

The issue is not happening always. it is happening randomly. Sometimes it is working fine for around 7 to 8 hours before it starts misbehaving again.

It seems like the server is not responding. For debugging purpose I checked the process list on the Database server by executing the query “show processlist;" and I found that there are multiple processes for the same query with state “updating”. It could be due to multiple retries from the gateway.  I am not able to follow that whether it is expected behavior (multiple same queries with state “updating”) or not.  Please see the attached screenshot.

[Database server process list][1]

We would like to understand why this is happening only sometimes and not always, and how does it recover? Are there any contributing factors from the server-side for this behavior? Are there any configurations that we need to do on our side? Any guidance is appreciated on this.

For your information:

I have used the MySQL_MariaDB_Generic library on the ESP32 Wi-Fi module to send data to the database.  Database table contains 7 data fields like Id,Timestamp,P1,P2,P3,P4,and P5. Here ‘Id ‘ is the primary key and Auto increment attribute.

Here data types for the data fields P3, P4, and P5 are MEDIUMBLOB.

Query to insert data fields Timestamp, P1, P2, P3:

```
INSERT INTO TabelXYZ(Timestamp, P1, P2, P3)VALUES ('TimestampValue','P1Value','P2Value','P3Value');
```

query to insert data field P4:

```
UPDATE TabelXYZ SET P4 = 'P4Value' WHERE Timestamp = 'TimestampValue' ORDER BY Timestamp;
```

query to insert data field P4:

```
UPDATE TabelXYZ SET P5 = 'P5Value' WHERE Timestamp = 'TimestampValue' ORDER BY Timestamp;
```

Please note that there is no internet connectivity issue here as the insert query is executing OK every time and only the update query is getting failed.

I am not able to find any root cause behind it.  Let me know if anyone has suggestions/idea about what I am doing wrong.

Comment: you are updating **all** rows, that takes time, if you really need it, increase  the timeouts

Comment: This is a database design issue rather than having anything to do with Arduino or ESP32. 1) you don't need to insert timestamp, design your database in such a way that timestamp will automatically insert when a record is created; 2) it slows because the timestamp field in your database is not indexed, it is better to user ID field for update because it is unique(auto-incremented) and indexed.